# Using HashMaps in Java

Tags: java

Basically I'm making this Java program in BlueJ, in which the player is in the world of The Lord of the Rings. I created separate packages for weapons, items etc. I have a class Main outside all the packages(in the main body of the project screen). In there, I tried something.

```
public static void test()throws Exception{
        System.out.println("There is a brass sword and an iron sword. Which do you want?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.next();
        HashMap options = new HashMap();
        options.put("brass", new Sword());
        options.put("iron", new Sword());
        Sword k = options.get(s);
}
```

I want the above method to return a Sword object to me. This does not work, unfortunately. Any help....?

Comment: Use parameterized type `HashMap`.

Comment: Also, never ever put a "throws Exception" at the end of your method, please. If your method may throw a checked exception, create a new Exception class and throw it.

Comment: @Rohit: Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Just use the parametrized type `HashMap`, declare the `HashMap` as

```
HashMap<String, Sword> options = new HashMap<String, Sword>();
```

> I want the above method to return a Sword object to me.

Then change the method return type and add a return to it:

```
public static Sword test()throws Exception{
        System.out.println("There is a brass sword and an iron sword. Which do you want?");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.next();
        HashMap<String, Sword> options = new HashMap<String, Sword>();
        options.put("brass", new Sword());
        options.put("iron", new Sword());
        Sword k = options.get(s);
        return k;
}
```

Comment: and he needs to change void to Sword

Comment: @R.J Yes I didn't notice the last part of the question, I updated, thanks

Comment: Since this seems to be "test code", parts of which may actually get copied to actual code, I'd prefer using interface as type `Map<String, Sword> options = new HashMap<String, Sword>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
public static Sword test()throws Exception{
    System.out.println("There is a brass sword and an iron sword. Which do you want?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.next();
    HashMap<String, Sword> options = new HashMap<String, Sword>();
    options.put("brass", new Sword());
    options.put("iron", new Sword());
    return options.get(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your method to return a Sword object you should change `public static void test()` to `public static Sword test()` and at the end of your method call `return sword`

Answer (score 0):

The default hashMap accepts two generic types `HashMap<Object,Object>` which represents `HashMap<Key,Value>` with your code you will have to cast the `options.get(s)` to `Sword` but with that you don't use the power of Generics so recommend the @BackSlash's answer since you won't need casting.

More on Generics:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm